# How to read an image as double in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to implement a similar function as shown below using the opencv.

```
image=double(imread('mask.jpg'));
```

I have implemented something like this.How to convert this into double.

```
cv::Mat image= imread(arg[1]);
```

where `arg[1]` contains my image which is to be stored in `Mat` image as double. How to implement this.

Comment: use this? image.convertTo(image,CV_64FC1);

Comment: It is not reading image as double. Image is read as uint8 then converted to double, which can be done as commented by azer89.

Comment: Is it possible to read image as double directly.If i do the above step i need to create two Mat object right?

Comment: @user2885090 I think there's now way to do that. There are only 5 options to load images  CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR , CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for [**`Mat::convertTo()`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto).

- For gray-scale image:

  ```
  image.convertTo(image, CV_64FC1);
  ```
- For color image:

  ```
  image.convertTo(image, CV_64FC3); // or CV_64FC4 for 4-channel image
  ```