# Opencv imread() to Mat_<float>

Tags: opencv

I was reading many images in my program and used following code to read each image.

```
cv::Mat_<float> LoadedImage = imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

And, it works for some images but not for all images. (Images are all JPG files)

I checked structure with VS 2010 debug mode and `LoadedImage` has following structure.

[Structure http://imageshack.com/a/img838/451/5n17.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img838/451/5n17.png)

Somehow rows are zero (**But cols are correct**). Is anyone able to explain to me why? :)

Thank you in advance.

I am putting code that I am currently using to avoid this issue. But I am not sure why that has to be done that way.

```
// Read image with imread() to Mat
cv::Mat LoadedImage_CharFormat = imread(fullfilename);  

// Convert to Gray image
if(LoadedImage_CharFormat.type() != CV_8UC1)
    cvtColor(LoadedImage_CharFormat, LoadedImage_CharFormat, CV_RGB2GRAY);

// Convert to Mat_<float> 
cv::Mat_<float> LoadedImage;
LoadedImage_CharFormat.convertTo(LoadedImage, CV_32F);
```

Here is image that you can try. http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img845/4624/y8h0.jpg

Comment: It seems it can not open the files properly!(`Bad Ptr`)

Comment: Yes, it cannot be opened properly. It shows correct cols but 0 rows. It is not just failed to open but I thought there is some other reason for that. I want to know that reason. :)

Comment: Did you try to open just that files! I mean that don't read them one by one to reach that bad image! Open it first and let us know! It is better if you can share you image with us

Comment: I tried to open that first. It still fails...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read an image as double in OpenCV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872016/how-to-read-an-image-as-double-in-opencv)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't read a grayscale(uchar) image directly into a float Mat.
instead,

```
Mat m = imread("image.jpg",0);
Mat_<float> fm;

m.convertTo(fm,CV_32F);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, it is right. I actually do exactly same way you wrote to avoid this issue. But strange thing is all of my images are color images. Some of them are fine with code that I posted but some of them are not.

Comment: Opps, I pressed enter and it just added comment. :) Anyway, all images are color but I don't know why some of them are just return with 0 rows. Is this something with internal type of JPG format? (Compression type?) Thank you.

Comment: no, the number of bytes supplied does not match witdh*height*channels*depth, think of it, a rgb pixel needs 3 bytes, the resp. float representaion needs 12.

Comment: Thank you barek. So your code's imread("imagefile.txt", 0) will save each pixel to 1 byte in Mat m and then this each pixel converts to float type in Mat_<float>, right?

Comment: By the way, I tried your code and it still fails on first line because it still reads 0 rows. To read rows correctly, I have to call imread("image.jpg") which means 2nd parameter is 1 (default). Here is image for you to test. http://imageshack.com/a/img845/4624/y8h0.jpg

Comment: berak, I added my current working code on my original post. Basically it is same code that you suggested except that I explicitly convert image to gray scale with cvtConvert() function. You used imread with second parameter as 0. Do you know why I have to do it that way?