# Issue with imread. Strange float values

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to simple load an image (TIFF) and display a pixel value.

If I open the image using ImageJ the values are 32-bit float. But opening the same image using opencv I get really strange float values, e.g. 4.2039e-44.

If I read the value of a specific pixel using "int" the presented value is correct. Below is the code I use to test. And here a link for the image: https://goo.gl/Wmv9xE.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::string imageFile = "image.tiff";

    cv::Mat image;
    image = cv::imread(imageFile, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);   // Read the file

    if (!image.data)                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open or find the image: " << imageFile << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "Image:" << image.rows << " x " << image.cols << " Channels: " << image.channels() << " Depth: " << image.depth() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value at 0,0: " << image.at<float>(0,1)<< std::endl; // Strange Value
    std::cout << "Value at 0,0: " << image.at<int>(0,1)<< std::endl; // Correct Value

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

*** Update ***

Trying to move forward with the code, I decided to create a function to convert the data to "int" reading from the file.
As a **temporary** solution this worked, but I'm still looking for the reason why the data is being loaded wrong.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::string imageFile = "/home/slepicka/XSConfig/image.tiff";

    cv::Mat image = openImage(imageFile);

    if (!image.data)                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open or find the image: " << imageFile << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "Image:" << image.rows << " x " << image.cols << " Channels: " << image.channels() << " Depth: " << image.depth() << " Type: " << image.type() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value at 0,0: " << image.at<int>(0,1)<< std::endl; // Correct Value
    //std::cout << "Data: " << image << std::endl;
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

cv::Mat openImage(std::string filename){
    cv::Mat imageLoad = cv::imread(filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);

    if(imageLoad.type() == CV_32F){
        return convertToInt(imageLoad);
    }

    return imageLoad;

}

cv::Mat convertToInt(cv::Mat source){
    int r, c;
    cv::Mat converted;

    converted.create(source.rows, source.cols, CV_32SC1);

    for (r=0; r<source.rows;r++) {
        for (c=0; c<source.cols;c++) {
            converted.at<int>(r, c) = source.at<int>(r, c);
        }
    }
    return converted;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this might help?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433860/opencv-imread-to-mat-float

Comment: please check image.depth() and image.type().  for sure, your image is **not** float by default (if you want that, you'll have to convert it explicitly)

Comment: @berak , the depth is 5 and the image type is also 5. The strange part is that if I open the Image with ImageJ it says that it's a float Image and all the informations from opencv tells me the same, right?

Comment: @aspiring_sarge, didn't worked for me! =(

Comment: Whatever ImageJ is showing is completely irrelevant. Every program converts rgb values to whatever it thinks is more convenient. I open this tiff in irfanview and see int rgb values. Why don't you drop CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH from imread or use CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE since that's what you have. Also why would you want a greyscale image stored in int? you are wasting memory. what you want is 8-bit image.

Comment: @RedOctober, the image is in fact photon count values and they are up to 32bits. That's why I want int values.

Comment: I see, well since this is not really an image data perhaps saving it to image is not the best idea. I don't know what program program saves it but you might want to look into some other formats like yaml for example. then you can get the raw data out and know exactly what you are dealing with. Image reading functions will make all sorts of assumptions which are reasonable to make when you are dealing with images. So you may very well end up with int data which is typed as float.

Comment: If you prefer to use the work around you already have, may i suggest to do conversion more efficiently. I don't have opencv installed right now so i can't check it but i'm sure you can d something like this:
Mat converted(source.size(),  CV_32SC1, source.data);

Comment: @RedOctober, The interesting part is that in Python for example the PIL library is able to open it very well! The image is generated by the detector software, so in this case there's no much that I can do! This workaround so far is dealing with this. Great! I will try your suggestion and I will post here the result! Thanks!

Comment: You might have to put "true" as the last parameter to make sure it actually copies the data: 
Mat converted(source.size(), CV_32SC1, source.data, true);

Comment: @RedOctober, it worked! =) Much better than my for looping. The previous comment about a segfault was my mistake! Thank you!